# Cosmos Db : Add Item in non existent parent using Patch

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Technologies: Cosmos DB Emulator, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.23.0

Goal : Add the first item of an array using Path Add

Initial data :

```
{
"id": "P1-86",
"ProjectType_Id": "1",
"Description": "AAA"
}
```

Requested final data :

```
  {
    "id": "P1-86",
    "ProjectType_Id": "1",
    "Description": "AAA",
    "Products" : [{"Id" : "P-1", "Description" : "My Product"}]
  }
```

My code :

```
PatchOperation operation = PatchOperation.Add("/Products/-", command);

TransactionalBatch batch = container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey(project_Id))
        .PatchItem(project_Id, new[] { operation },
        new TransactionalBatchPatchItemRequestOptions
        {
                    EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                    IndexingDirective = IndexingDirective.Exclude
        });

TransactionalBatchResponse batchResponse = await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```

I get a BadRequest Error.

I try :

"/Products/"  => insert the item as an object and not as an array's item

```
  {
    "id": "P1-86",
    "ProjectType_Id": "1",
    "Description": "AAA",
    "Products" : {"Id" : "P-1", "Description" : "My Product"}
  }
```

"/Products/0/" => BadRequest

"/Products/0"  => BadRequest

"/Products/-"  => BadRequest

"/Products/-/" => BadRequest

"/Products//" => BadRequest

According to the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

> Add   Add performs one of the following, depending on the target path:
> If the target path specifies an element that does not exist, it is
> added. If the target path specifies an element that already exists,
> its value is replaced. If the target path is a valid array index, a
> new element will be inserted into the array at the specified index. It
> shifts existing elements to the right. If the index specified
> is equal to the length of the array, it will append an element to the
> array. Instead of specifying an index, you can also use the -
> character. It will also result in the element being appended to the
> array.
>
> Note: Specifying an index greater than the array length will result in
> an error.

Is there a Cosmos Db Emulator limitation ?
What's wrong with my code?

---

Edit 1 :

More informations :
If initial data are :

```
{
"id": "P1-86",
"ProjectType_Id": "1",
"Description": "AAA",
"Products" : []
}
```

PatchOperation.Add("/Products/-", command);  => Work

but in my case the Products array didn't previously exists (migration of data model)

Comment: You have to patch explicit property paths for this to work. Each property requires its own patch operation for ID and Description. You can't send an object

Comment: If the Products Property already exist, it's work correctly, it didn't work only if the initial Property array (Products) is not defined.

Comment: I've try "/Products/0/Id" but it doestn't work if Products is not defined initialy (but works fine if it is). It seem we couldn't create a new array if the property doestn't exists...

Comment: Did you try .add for products first, then subsequent patch operations for the other items within the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finaly I think that it's not possible to do what i want automaticaly.

From Exception Message when you didn't use Transaction :

> BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId:
> c12f915a-3c4a-4d76-bd7d-ad519bbb8f02; Reason: (Message:
> {"Errors":["For Operation(1): Add Operation can only create a child
> object of an existing node(array or object) and cannot create path
> recursively, no path found beyond: 'Products'.

So I manage to do it by my self, it's not realy cleaver but it's work's.

```
try
{
PatchOperation operationAdd = PatchOperation.Add("/Products/-", command);
var patchAddResponse = await container.PatchItemAsync<ProjectResponse>(project_Id, new PartitionKey(project_Id), new[] { operationAdd },
new PatchItemRequestOptions
            {
                FilterPredicate = $"from c where IS_DEFINED(c.Products) AND c.id = '{project_Id}'",
                EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
                IndexingDirective = IndexingDirective.Exclude
            });

        this.log.LogInformation($"ru : {patchAddResponse.RequestCharge} - AddProductAsync " + command.Id);

        return patchAddResponse.Resource;

    }
    catch (CosmosException ex)
    {
        if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed)
        {
            PatchOperation operationCreate = PatchOperation.Add("/Products", new IProduct[] { command });

            var patchCreateResponse = await container.PatchItemAsync<ProjectResponse>(project_Id, new PartitionKey(project_Id), new[] { operationCreate },
           new PatchItemRequestOptions
           {
               EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false,
               IndexingDirective = IndexingDirective.Exclude
           });

            this.log.LogInformation($"ru : {patchCreateResponse.RequestCharge} - AddProductAsync " + command.Id);

            return patchCreateResponse.Resource;
        }

        else
            throw ex;
}
```

precondition use 1 RU so it's acceptable

Comment: This worked for me, I also extended to help with the situation where the property is there, but NULL. The fix for this situation was to perform a set instead of an add to set the array to the list of 1 item, catching a bad request status code

Comment: Let's say you used etag in the attempt to write, and the etag condition failed. That would also give a PreconditionFailed exception. I wonder if it is possible to distinguish between that, and the case when the path doesn't exist.